Trigger rule "one_success" doesn't work for "DataprocCreateClusterOperator"
I have a case that one of my operators which is DataprocCreateClusterOperator never triggers as if "all_success" was still set for it. It runs fine if it's the very first task but I don't want to create a cluster each time the dag runs as it might not be needed. To my suprise putting upstreams on it and setting it as "one_success" doesn't work.
I know that "one_success" rule works in general because "exit_task" has it set up and it always run without a problem.

Here is my code:
    check_cm_files_present_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='check_cm_files_present_task',
    python_callable=check_cm_files_present,
)

check_cmts_struct_files_present_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='check_cmts_struct_files_present_task',
    python_callable=check_cmts_struct_files_present,
)

check_cmts_meas_files_present_task = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='check_cmts_meas_files_present_task',
    python_callable=check_cmts_meas_files_present,
)
move_to_valid_cm = BashOperator(
    task_id='move_to_valid_cm',
    bash_command='''gsutil -m mv gs://A gs://B,
    dag = dag
    )
move_to_valid_cmts_struct = BashOperator(
    task_id='move_to_valid_cmts_struct',
    bash_command='''gsutil -m mv gs://C gs://D,
    dag = dag
    )
move_to_valid_cmts_meas = BashOperator(
    task_id='move_to_valid_cmts_meas',
    bash_command='''gsutil -m mv gs://E gs://F,
    dag = dag
    )

create_dataproc_cluster = dataproc_operator.DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
    task_id='create_dataproc_cluster',
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_WITH_DATE,
    project_id=PROJECT,
    cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
    region='europe-west3',
    trigger_rule='one_success'
)

exit_task = DummyOperator(
    task_id='exit_task',
    trigger_rule='one_success'
)

check_cm_files_present_task >> move_to_valid_cm >> run_dataproc_job_cm
check_cm_files_present_task >> exit_task

check_cmts_struct_files_present_task >> move_to_valid_cmts_struct >> run_dataproc_job_cmts_struct
check_cmts_struct_files_present_task >> exit_task

check_cmts_meas_files_present_task >> move_to_valid_cmts_meas >> run_dataproc_job_cmts_meas
check_cmts_meas_files_present_task >> exit_task

[move_to_valid_cm, move_to_valid_cmts_struct, move_to_valid_cmts_meas] >> create_dataproc_cluster >> [run_dataproc_job_cm, run_dataproc_job_cmts_struct, run_dataproc_job_cmts_meas]


This skip state from BranchPythonOperator cascades to downstream tasks till it meets  trigger_rule=none_failed_min_one_success.
The idea behind it is that when you are branching you want to skip the whole irrelevant branch. However in some cases like yours you want to decide when to stop the cascade.
Airflow docs explain this scenario:
join = EmptyOperator(task_id="join", dag=dag)

As you can see the join task is skipped because one of the upstream is branch operator that that sent a skip "signal" and join task is part of this branch.

However join is also part of the success branch so if we change it's trigger rule to
join = EmptyOperator(task_id="join", trigger_rule="none_failed_min_one_success ", dag=dag)

Airflow will not cascade the skip signal further and let the scheduler handle the join task.

In your case, you need to replace one_success with none_failed_min_one_success:
create_dataproc_cluster = dataproc_operator.DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
    task_id='create_dataproc_cluster',
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_WITH_DATE,
    project_id=PROJECT,
    cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
    region='europe-west3',
    trigger_rule='none_failed_min_one_success'
)


Hi, I changed it as suggested to "none_failed_min_one_success" but it doesn't seem to made any difference. The join task is still being skipped

I am not able to reproduce your issue. Is the code you shared in the question your real code?

No, it's not. But I found the source of my issues: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19222

This was a bug in older version of Airflow. If you are running old version it is recommended to upgrade as soon as possible.
